# Varnish: having trouble getting basic caching to work as expected

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm learning Varnish, and I am having trouble understanding some very basics. I have created a simple file i want Varnish to store in cache, called **test.php** and it looks like this:

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0, s-maxage=3600" ); // <-- This should make Varnish cache, right?
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
        <h1> test </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

With these headers, I expected Varnish to store the file in cache for an hour(3600 seconds).  However when i run **varnishlog -b -o -i TxURL**(To monitor request to backend), i can see that there is traffic. Like this:

```
13 BackendClose b default
13 BackendOpen  b default 127.0.0.1 57857 127.0.0.1 8080
13 TxURL        b /test.php
13 BackendReuse b default
13 TxURL        b /test.php
13 BackendReuse b default
13 TxURL        b /test.php
```

How can I make Varnish cache this file, and not contact the backend each time?

Answer (score 0):

I checked firebug and i found a Cookie in the header. I have no idea why there is a cookie there, but i updated my **vcl** file with this:

```
sub vcl_recv{
    if (req.http.cookie){
            unset req.http.cookie;
    }
}
```

Varnish is configured by default, to not cache, when there is a cookie header present in the request.